# Accessing a specific node which is also used in other areas in the file

Tags: php, xml

If I have the following data in my XML file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
<PmtInf>
      <PmtInfId>5n7gfUaPGK</PmtInfId>
      <PmtMtd>DD</PmtMtd>
      <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
      <CtrlSum>200.2</CtrlSum>
      <PmtTpInf>
        <SvcLvl>
          <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
        </SvcLvl>
        <LclInstrm>
          <Cd>CORE</Cd>
        </LclInstrm>
        <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
      </PmtTpInf>
      <DrctDbtTxInf>
      <PmtId>
          <EndToEndId>nmu5AOhE7G</EndToEndId>
      </PmtId>
      </DrctDbtTxInf>
 </PmtInf>
 <PmtInf>
      <PmtInfId>5jAcoNoId3</PmtInfId>
      <PmtMtd>DD</PmtMtd>
      <NbOfTxs>3</NbOfTxs>
      <CtrlSum>100.5</CtrlSum>
      <PmtTpInf>
        <SvcLvl>
          <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
        </SvcLvl>
        <LclInstrm>
          <Cd>CORE</Cd>
        </LclInstrm>
        <SeqTp>FRST</SeqTp>
      </PmtTpInf>
      <DrctDbtTxInf>
          <PmtId>
              <EndToEndId>nmu5AbdfG</EndToEndId>
          </PmtId>
      </DrctDbtTxInf>
      <DrctDbtTxInf>
          <PmtId>
              <EndToEndId>nmu5A3r5jgG</EndToEndId>
          </PmtId>
      </DrctDbtTxInf>
</PmtInf>
</CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
</Document>
```

How would I access `<NbOfTxs>` in the second `<PmtInf>` block (where the value is 3) instead of `<NbOfTxs>` in the first `<PmtInf>` block (where the value is 1)?

If I just used the following line of code;

```
$FRSTTransaction = $xml->getElementsByTagName('NbOfTxs')->nodeValue;
```

It doesn't know which `<NbOfTxs>` I am attempting to access.

The only difference between each payment block is the `<SeqTp>`. There will be 4 Payment Blocks in total.

I am trying to count the number of `<DrctDbtTxInf>`blocks in each Payment Block and then put this value into `<NbOfTxs>`.

```
      <PmtId>
          <EndToEndId>nmu5AOhE7G</EndToEndId>
      </PmtId>
      </DrctDbtTxInf>
```

The code I tried is as follows;

```
$filename = date('Y-W').'.xml'; //2014-26.xml
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load($filename);
$NumberTransactions = 0;
$RCURTransaction = $xml->getElementsByTagName('DrctDbtTxInf');
$NodeValue = $xml->getElementsByTagName('NbOfTxs')->nodeValue;
foreach ($RCURTransaction as $Transaction) {
$NodeValue = $NodeValue + 1;
}

$Document = simplexml_load_file($filename);
$Document->CstmrDrctDbtInitn->PmtInf->NbOfTxs = $NodeValue; 
$Document->asXML($filename);
```

I receive no errors, it just doesnt seem to access the node value.

Comment: How did you parse the XML (`DOMDocument`, I suspect)? What errors did you get? Accurately describe the problem, and tell us what you've tried so far to fix it

Comment: I edited my post if you want to take a look, im really new to XML so sorry if I am not making myself clear..

Comment: I've noticed your edit, you've actually added another question to this one (how to count the child-nodes + update an xml file). I'm adding the answer to that to my answer. PS: accepting an answer from time to time gives people more incentive to actually bother to answer your question. Vote if an answer helps, so people feel that the time and effort the put into writing an answer is appreciated

Comment: Updated my answer: added example code of how to update, create add, find nodes _and_ save the updated XML file, in one fell swoop

Comment: I always accept and vote if an answer helps, I really appreciate the time and effort ye put into helping me. I will try your answer now and get back to you straight away with the result. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, hope you don't mind, but I casted close votes on some of your other questions. If you don't get an answer right away, don't post the question over and over, please. Try updating your question, adding mode details and be more specific. If you post the same question over and over, that is seen as spamming, and will get you flagged for moderator attention, and eventually banned from this site. Read through the help section of this site for details. (this is just a friendly wanring, I did _not_ flag you for spamming... just so you know :-P)

Comment: @user3266484: Do not duplicate your own questions, instead, edit the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php). `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName` does not return a node, it returns an instance of the `DOMNodeList` class. This class implements the `Traversable` interface (which means you can `foreach` it), and has *one* method of its own `item` (cf, again, [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php)).

You are attempting to access the `nodeValue` property of what you *think* is a `DOMNode` instance, but is in fact a `DOMNodeList` instance. As you can see [in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), there is no `nodeValue` property available. Instead, get a specific node from this list, and then get the node value:

```
$nodes = $xml->getElementsByTagName('NbOfTxs');
foreach ($nodes as $node)
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;//first, second, third node
```

Or, if you want, for example to see the value of just the third occurrence of this node:

```
if ($nodes->length > 2)//zero-indexed!
    echo $nodes->item(2)->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Error, only ', $nodes->length, ' occurrences of that node found', PHP_EOL;
```

Bottom line, as often, really is RTM. The documentation for `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName` clearly shows what the return type of the given method is. if it's an instance of a particular class, that return type is clickable on the PHP website, and links you through to the manual page of that class. Navigating an API couldn't be simpler than that, IMHO:

```
//from the docs
public DOMNodeList DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName ( string $name )
       //          class::methodName                  arguments + expected type
       |-> return type, links to docs for this class
```

*Update*
Addressing the things you mention in your updated question:

- How to count specific children for a node

I'm assuming each `PmtInf` is a payment block, but all the `SeqTp` tags seem to me, to be children of `PmtTpInf` tags. Since we're working with a `DOMNodeList`, which consists of `DOMNode` instances. [Looking at the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) is the first thing to do. As you can see, each `DOMNode` has numerous, handy properties and methods: `$childNodes`, `$nodeName` and `$parentNode` are the ones we will be using here.

```
$payments = $xml->getElementsByTagName('PmtTpInf');//don't get PmtInf, we can access that through `PmtTpInf` nodes' parentNode property
$idx = -1;
$counts = array();
$parents = array();
foreach ($payments as $payment)
{
    if (!$parents || $parents[$idx] !== $payment->parentNode)
    {//current $payment is not a child of last processed payment block
        $parents[++$idx] = $payment->parentNode;//add reference to new payment block
        $count[$idx] = 0;//set count to 0
    }
    foreach ($payment->childNodes as $child)
    {
        if ($child->nodeName === 'SeqTp')
            ++$counts[$idx];//add 1 to count
    }
}
```

Ok, now we have 2 arrays, `$parents`, which contains each payment block, and `$counts`, which contains the total count of all `SeqTp` blocks in that payment block. Let's set about adding/updating that data:

```
foreach ($parents as $idx => $block)
{//iterate over the payment blocks
    $nbNode = null;//no node found yet
    for ($i=0;$i<$block->childNodes->length;++$i)
    {
        if ($block->childNodes->item($i)->nodeName === 'NbOfTxs')
        {
            $nbNode = $block->childNodes->item($i);
            break;//found the node, stop here
        }
    }
    if ($nbNode === null)
    {//NbOfTxs tag does not exist yet
        $nbNode = $xml->createElement('NbOfTxs', 0);//create new node
        $block->appendChild($nbNode);//add as child of the payment-block node
    }
    $nbNode->nodeValue = $counts[$idx];//set value using the counts array we constructed above
}
```

Lastly, to save this updated XML dom:

```
$xml->save($filename);
```

That's all, no need for `simplexml_load_file` at all, because that parses the XML DOM, which `DOMDocument` already did for you.